# webBrowser invoke click

Tags: html, button, invoke

This is the html I am working with:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Type name to search contacts or enter number"    name="contactsornum" class="revertBlueBorder" id="tMobileNumber">
<span class="add-contact" style=""></span>
```

when a number is entered into this field a blue plus icon comes up and you click on it to add the number to listbox
I need to invoke a click on this icon/link/ add-contact button
I have recently tried the following with no success:

```
Private Sub addContact_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles addContact.Click

      WebBrowser1.document.GetElementById("tmobilenumber").InvokeMember("click")

  End Sub
```

does anyone know how I can click on this button that seems to be sitting inside the textfield?

thanks

Comment: It's not obvious what you are asking. Add a clear question with a question mark and it might help you get an answer quicker.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I want to click the button on the inside the text box that appears when a number is entered.